# Python - match all repetition of a char between groups of chars

Tags: python, regex, char, grouping, substitution

I've a little problem with a regex best described below:

Original string is:

```
{reply_to={message_type=login}|login_id=pippo|user_description=pippo=pluto|version=2013.2.1|utc_offset=7200|login_date=2014-07-03|login_time=09:43:02|error=0}
```

This is what I would like to obtain:

```
{reply_to:{message_type:login}|login_id:pippo|user_description:pippo=pluto|version:2013.2.1|utc_offset:7200|login_date:2014-07-03|login_time:09:43:02|error:0}
```

It happens that if there is an "=" also in the value of the key I cannot substitute it.

What I've tried to do is to match and substitute grouping a set of chars:

```
re.sub(r'([\{\}\|])=([\{\}\|])',r'\1":"\2',modOutput)
```

Obiously it doens't work! Any Idea ?

Comment: Could you please *describe* what the substitution shall do? It is hard to compare the two strings and spot all the differences.

Comment: why you removed the `|` symbol before the version?

Comment: Sorry I made some mistake in the code. Now is what I need. To summarize I need to substitute the fist "=" char between }{| chars.

Comment: your code replaces {or}or|followed by a = sign then followed by {or}or| with {or}or|:{or}or|

Comment: @Avinash Raj exat what i need to do

Comment: but your input doesn't contain the above mentioned format. I'm talking about = sign which was immediate after to { or } or |

Comment: why is one `=` not replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works at least with the given example:

```
re.sub(r'=([^{|}]*)', r':\1', s)
```

We're looking for a `=`, then capturing up to the next delimiter (one of `{|}`) in order to skip over subsequent `=` signs.